# How do I access text value from .failure case

Tags: ios, swift

I am displaying an error message to the UI sent from my backend but cannot figure out how to simply print the string to the console, by printing *error* I get " Message("error string") " but I just want "error string"

I tried the following but they don't work:

```
print(error.message)
print(error.localizedDescription)
print(error.rawValue)
```

below is my code

```
switch value {
case .success(let response):
       // deal with response
case .failure(let error):
       print(error) // prints " Message("error message") "
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             signupNavigationViewModel.signupErrorMessage = "\(error)"
               return
          }
}
```

```
// Data / Decoding model
enum Response: Decodable {
    case success(UserResponse)
    case failure(String)
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case success, user, token, message
    }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        
        if success {
            let user = try container.decode(User.self, forKey: .user)
            let token = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
            self = .success(UserResponse(user: user, token: token))
        } else {
            let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
            self = .failure(message)
        }
    }
}
```

** UPDATED WITH RESPONSE CODE **

My json response comes back as a string (see -> below) and "message" is
added from client code and prints as "*message("password cannot contain the
word password")*"

```
const message = err.message.replace("User validation failed: password:","") 
console.log(message) 
-> password cannot contain the word password
```

Comment: And what does your json contain when `success` is false?

Comment: Your failure block is not returning Error type, it returns String type - `case failure(String)`

Comment: What's inside `let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)`? Also can you show your `Message` struct? Most probably you might need to do something in the custom decoding, before `self = .failure(message)` as it looks like it's converting a Message struct with a value inside into a String, and then is too late.

Comment: In your `case .failure(let error): print(error) // prints " Message("error message") "`, `error` is already a String. Because you are switching over `Response` type and not a `Result<..., Error>` type. So you already should send yourself the right `String` here which is done in the `self = .failure(message)`.

Comment: But just show us the JSON example with the "Message" containing the error, so we can help you build the right struct and decode correctly.

Comment: I have updated the code with the JSON @denis_lor. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to extract the string

1. Split the text by double quotes and get the second item

   ```
   let string = " Message(\"error message\") "
   let message = string.split(separator: "\"")[1]
   ```
2. Find the text inside the parentheses With Regular Expression

   ```
   let message = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s?Message\\(\"([^\"]+)\"\\)\\s?", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
   ```